# Hibernate deep deproxy

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy

I have problem with deproxy object in Hibernate. I used for deproxy object     `Hibernate.initialize()` and worked good. But now I create new project and new structure show like this:

**Car:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car", uniqueConstraints ={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id")})
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="car", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
    private List<CarComponents> components= new LinkedList<CarComponents>();
    public List<CarComponents> getCarComponents() {
        return this.version;
    }
    public void setCarComponents(List<CarComponents> components) {
        this.components= components;
    }
    ........ Next settings .....
}
```

**Car components:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car_components", uniqueConstraints ={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id")})
public class CarComponents implements Serializable {
    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id")
    private Car car;
    ........ Next settings .....
}
```

**Application code:**

```
... create session and transaction ... 

//getAll
List<Car> query = this.session.createQuery('from Car').list();
Hibernate.initialize(query)

... close session and transaction ...


for (Car item : query) {
    for(CarComponents component : item.getCarComponents()){
       System.out.println("id = "+item.getId()+" components = "+component.getName());
    }
}
```

Hibernate initialize working only for car but not for car component. How use Hibernate initialize to operate for all strukture(objects) in car (with car components)?

**EDIT**

I find problem. Problem is method: 
`public Car car(){
return this.car;
};`
in Class CarComponents. If I return null program is ok but when I return car object program show error. Is it same problem with deproxy ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all is int this code should return components??

```
public List<CarComponents> getCarComponents() {
        return this.version;
    }
```

And

```
 List<Car> cars = this.session.createQuery('from Car').list();
        Hibernate.initialize(cars)// this is not needed
```

As we called list() method, hibernate will fire a query to get list of cars from database. 
To initialize carComponents,  iterate through all cars

```
for(Car car : cars){
   Hibernate.initialize(car.getCarComponents());//here Hibernate will fire a query to load car components of the particular car
}
```

Comment: "First of all is int this code should return components??
`public List<CarComponents> getCarComponents() {
        return this.version;
    }`" : here is my fault. No` this.version` but `this.components`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch car components using the HQL:

```
List<Car> query = this.session.createQuery('from Car car left join fetch car.carComponents').list();
```

`Hibernate.initialize()` doesn't work for "deep deproxy" cause otherwise it could fetch the whole database in a single call :)

Comment: When I used your HQL showed me to **error:**
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)`